# Why am I getting "permission denied" when connecting to my NFS share?

Tags: server, permissions, nfs

On Ubuntu version 17.04, my NFS shares are defined as follows:

## Configuration

In `/etc/exports`:

```
/bottle/media 192.168.0.0/16(ro,all_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534) 10.3.0.0/16(rw,all_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
```

UNIX file permissions for the shared volume:

```
$ ls -al /bottle
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root       3 Sep  3 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root   root    4096 Sep  3 00:37 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 nobody nogroup    2 Sep  3 11:45 media
```

## Verification

Ran `sudo exportfs`:

```
/bottle/media   192.168.0.0/16
/bottle/media   10.3.0.0/24
```

Checked the NFS server daemon:

```
$ sudo systemctl status nfs-server
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-09-03 12:09:47 BST; 16min ago
  Process: 23350 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23344 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23337 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23380 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23374 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 23380 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Sep 03 12:09:47 monolith systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Sep 03 12:09:47 monolith systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

Verified that the UID/GID settings correspond to `nobody` and `nogroup`, respectively:

```
$ id -u nobody
65534

$ getent group nogroup
nogroup:x:65534:
```

## Symptoms

The NFS server host is located at `10.3.0.100`.  The client (OSX Sierra v10.12.6) is at `10.3.0.102`.

I attempted a connection using finder's "Connect to Server"  dialogue (`cmd + k`), into which I entered `nfs://10.3.0.100`.

Doing so yields the following error:  `You do not have permission to access this server`.

### Is this a configuration problem?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: With macOS you must add `insecure` to your export. It would look as so. `10.3.0.0/16 (rw,all_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,insecure)` and also you must connect with the actual export, not the root folder, `nfs://10.3.0.100/bottle/media`

Comment: @nullmeta, that did the trick.  Many thanks!  Feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to connect to the NFS share with MacOS, the share must be defined with the insecure flag. All that means is its allowing a connection from a non standard port (which macOS uses). So your export line would look like this.

```
10.3.0.0/16 (rw,all_squash,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,insecure)
```

Also, when connecting from mac (especially on nfsv3) you have to connect to a specific exported folder rather than the root folder or just the IP.

```
nfs://10.3.0.100/bottle/media
```

Should do the trick!